# Accepting two conditional offers

Tags: united-kingdom, ielts

I got two conditional offers for postgradute courses from two universities. The English requirements are a bit lower for one university (IELTS 6 with 5.5 in each section) than for the other (IELTS 6.5 with 6 in each section).

Since I will know my IELTS results next month at the earliest, I do not know which offer I should accept because I have to decide by the end of this month.

Is it acceptable to accept both offers? I am fine with paying the deposit or other fees even if they are unrefundable.

Comment: Couldn't you just tell them exactly that? "I am waiting for my IELTS results and cannot definitely accept your offer yet, but I am certainly still interested." I would not firmly accept and then still weasel out.

Comment: Since your offers are conditional, what do their rules say about accepting an offer and finding out later that you can't fulfill the conditions?

Comment: @Lawrence I suspect that Elastic Lamb is asking about the consequences of accepting the lower IELTS offer. If they fulfill the higher offer, then they will also have fulfilled the lower offer.

Comment: @MJeffryes Thanks, that makes sense. I don't see an ethical problem with the OP using the other uni as a safety net, especially since he/she is willing to bear any financial penalties for backing out after accepting. The terms of the offer should explain any other consequences, but the OP should consider contacting the uni to clarify this.